# Count the documents based on date in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am newbee to mongodb

Tried to count the documents based on field value in the collection.
I used to insert DATE () when inserting.
But while count the document,it didn't show output

```
 { 
    "_id" : 6, 
    "WebUser" : "F",
    "PassWord" : "F", 
    "MailId" : "F@mail.com",
    "Country" : "In",
    "Contact" : { "Mobile" : "6" },
    "DOJ" : "Thu Jan 05 2017 16:55:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
 }
```

Tried the below options.But no use.

```
db.WebUser.count( { DOJ: { $gt: new Date('01/01/2017') } } )
0
db.WebUser.count( { DOJ : { $gt: new Date('01-05-2017 16:55:08') } } )
0
db.WebUser.count( { DOJ : { $gt: new Date('Thu Jan 05 2017 16:55:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time') } } )
0
```

How to handle the DATE in mongo db for  find ( Select ), Update and Delete.
How to convert from date to string and string to date?
How to add a month/year/day like Day+1,Month+5
What is the difference beteween date and isodate

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to inserting the record as

```
db.test.insert({date: new Date()})
```

saves date as : { "_id" : ObjectId("586e3e258fcf67917c9d4cb4"), "date" : ISODate("2017-01-05T12:37:57.450Z") }

but i think you insert it as

```
db.test.insert({date: Date()})
```

which convert the date into string. Which save date as { "_id" : ObjectId("586e3e328fcf67917c9d4cb5"), "date" : "Thu Jan 05 2017 18:08:10 GMT+0530 (IST)" }
as yours

Comment: Hi All,  Thanks for your info. What is  difference between New Date() and  Date ()?

Comment: new Date() return the instace of date object. while Date() return the date in string format.

Answer (score 0):

Your documents have simple strings in `DOJ` field. It's not `Date` objects. You should insert Date objects when you are inserting documents:

```
db.WebUser.insert({_id:6,Country:"In",DOJ:new Date("01/01/2017")})
```

After that you'll see correct type of data in `DOJ` field:

```
{
    "_id" : 6,
    "Country" : "In",
    "DOJ" : ISODate("2016-12-31T18:30:00Z")
}
```

BUT you can easily fix your data. Just select all documents with `DOJ` field of type string and update those documents:

```
db.WebUser.find({"DOJ":{$type:2}}).forEach(function(doc){
   db.WebUser.update({_id:doc._id},{$set:{DOJ:new Date(doc.DOJ)}})
})
```

After running this script your documents will have date in correct data format and your queries will work fine.